# AsyncValidator and debounceTime not working well

Tags: angular

Here is my AsyncValidator:

```
export class UniqueUriDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  myObservable: Observable<ValidationErrors>

  constructor() {}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> {

    if (!this.myObservable) {
      this.myObservable = new Observable<ValidationErrors>((observer) => {
        control.valueChanges
          .debounceTime(1000)
          .subscribe((value: string) => {
            console.log("Checking validation: " + value)
            observer.next({ "uriInUse": true })
            observer.complete()
          })
      })
    }

    return this.myObservable
  }

}
```

Since `validate()` is called every time the user changes the input, I am returning a reused single instance of Observable.

The validator works in the sense the control is marked as invalid. But the problem is that `debounceTime()` is causing the last entered value to be fired many times (one for each keystroke). That kind of defeats the purpose of using `debounceTime()`.

I tried this alternative approach:

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> {

  if (!this.myObservable) {
    this.myObservable = control.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .map(value => {
          console.log("Firing: " + value)
          return { "uriInUse": true }
        })
  }

  return this.myObservable
}
```

This causes `debounceTime()` work correctly and the subscribe handler gets called only once within one second. But this does not mark the control as invalid.

How do I correctly use `debounceTime()` to avoid having to run the validation logic for every keystroke?

Comment: Did you mean to use debounceTime or throttleTime?

Comment: debounceTime() is what is normally used in this situation.